# Zend Framework routing

Tags: zend-framework, routes

I'm trying to setup some routes for my ZF app but not getting too far. I have a controller 'WebServiceController', it has an index action and a lookupTransaction action. I want to use routes like this:

ws/

ws/lookupTransaction

Ideally I'd like anything with a 'ws/' prefix to go to the WebServiceController and match the action name. I'm not sure how to do that yet but I am trying to get each route working so I added these two routes:

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

    function _initRoutes()
    {
        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $router = $frontController->getRouter();

        $router->addRoute('ws', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('ws/', array(
            'controller'    =>  'web-service',
            'action'        =>  'index',
        )));

        $router->addRoute('ws/lookupTransaction', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('ws/lookupTransaction', array(
            'controller'    =>  'web-service',
            'action'        =>  'lookup-transaction',
        )));
    }

}
```

The first one works as expected but the second one doesn't, I just get 'Application Error'. What am I doing wrong? Just out of interest, if I remove my two routes and try and go to:

web-service/lookup-transaction

I still get the same error!

## Solved

Here is how I can make it work with camel cased action name and camel cased URL.

```
$router->addRoute('ws', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('ws/:action', array(
    'controller'    =>  'web-service',
    'action'        =>  'index',
)));
$router->addRoute('ws-lookupTransaction', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('ws/lookupTransaction', array(
    'controller'    =>  'web-service',
    'action'        =>  'lookup-transaction',
)));
```

Thanks

Ziad

Comment: And does your WebServiceController have a lookupTransactionAction?

Comment: BTW You could turn on error logging and check the logs for the specific cause (could be that you have the action defined but haven't defined a view/disabled rendering on the view, which will raise an exception).

Comment: Thanks wimvds, I do have the action but I didn't have the environment setup properly so was not getting the full error messages, that's fixed now.

Comment: Just wondering: doesn't it make more sense to configure the custom routes with the actual controller name and action name instead of the url'd versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just this one route as a solution to both problems:

```
$router->addRoute('ws', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('ws/:action', array(
    'controller'    =>  'web-service',
    'action'        =>  'index',
)));
```

the action parameter then serves as a default, so if no action is specified in the URL, index will be used. Otherwise it will route to the action in the URL. So `example.com/ws/lookupTransaction` will go to `lookuptransactionAction()` in your controller.

If this still gives you an error, post the error message so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Now 'ws/' resolves to the write controller/action but neither 'ws/lookup-transaction' nor 'ws/lookupTransaction' work. I created another action in the controller called 'test' and 'ws/test' works fine so it looks like there is some issue with how ZF handles camel cased actions. So your solution caters for my general scenario but I need to figure out how to do camel cased actions properly.

Comment: Here's a quick reference: http://www.papayasoft.com/2010/12/22/zend-framework-routing-hyphen-camelcase/ so going by that, lookuptransactionAction() should be the correct method name. Either way the error message should include what method it was looking for.

Comment: OK first up there was a silly mistake on my part, I had the view named lookup_transaction.phtml instead of lookup-transaction.phtml and I had my setup wrong so it wasn't showing the reason for the failure so now I fixed that and it works (BTW how do I configure ZF to use _ instead of - for views?).

Answer (score 0):

The router actually transforms URLs to lowercase. So the correct URL should be all lowercase dash separated words. Also I'm not sure if it's possible to use slash in route name (the first parameter of `addRoute()`).